# SVG Horizontal lines too big

Tags: svg

I tried to draw a shape using html/svg. It is a volume control, see below

```html
<svg height="20" width="90" style="background-color: #ccc;">
    <g>
        <rect x="10" y="0" width="80" height="20" style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1; fill: #fff;"></rect>
        <!-- Example two of four -->
        <polygon points="10,20 50,10 50,20" style="fill: rgba(128,128,128,128)"></polygon>

        <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="20" style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1;"></line>
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="20" style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1;"></line>
        <line x1="70" y1="0" x2="70" y2="20" style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1;"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

All browsers draw the horzontal lines double width, except the last one. I even added "stroke-width: 1", but that doesn't work.

I guess anti-aliasing? How can I fix this?

Comment: It happens because half of the line falls outside the svg element. To understand what is happening addd `svg{overflow:visible}` in the css. Alternatively you may try to increase the height of the svg element

Comment: because if your canvas has height 20 and you draw a horizontal line at y=20, the bottom half of it will be off the edge of the canvas.

Comment: I tried overflow:visible and it seems all the lines are in fact too big.